# wordpress visual comomposer change post link

Tags: wordpress

it'is my fiest question, that's my project, [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nidu.png)

because I use the wordpress in a part of my project,I want to add '&cc=11' to my post link,like the third image,that's I want

great apprrciate for you!
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65j9j.png)

[third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbfTI.png)